# Issue with the derivative term in Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm currently taking an introduction to machine learning course on coursea, and I am experiencing some issues with a gradient descent algorithm that I have to implement.

I’ll have two data points, and I’ll try to fit a line through those data points using gradient descent:

X      Y
23    406
98    432

Where the equation of the line is y = 0 + 1*x , and initially 0 = 0 and 1 = 0.

The gradient descent algorithm essentially does many iterations trying to optimize the values of 0 and 1 so that the cost function, defined as:

J(θ0,θ1)=(1 / 2m ) * ∑i=1-->m (hθ(x^(i))−y^(i))^2

is at a minimum. ( h(x) is the regression line equation y = 0 + 1*x )
(also I can't upload more than two links. So you can google "gradient descent cost function, and the second result on google images will show exactly the equation I'm talking about)

In each iteration, the gradient descent algorithm updates the values of 0 and 1 as so:

[image]

where alpha is the learning rate of the algorithm, and the large summation term is the derivative of the cost function, defined as

[image]

Now clearly, 0 and 1 should increase each iteration to create a line with positive slope. The regression equation given by desmos for this data returns the line: y = 0.346x + 398.

However, if we calculate the derivative term for this set of data points, in the first iteration I calculated:

d/d0 [J(0)] = -419

d/d1 [J(1)] = -25837

Which means that the values of 0 and 1 are decreasing, contrary to what should be happening.

I have isolated my problem to be with this single derivative term. My data diverges with the values of  getting more and more negative, and my cost function increasing after each iteration.

If anyone could help me troubleshoot this issue; make sure I'm actually calculating the derivative term correct first of all, and if I am, what else may be going wrong, that would be great.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question would probably better on Math: https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Math](http://Math.StackExchange.com) group.

Answer (score 0):

They are increasing because since the derivative is negative and when updating you subtract alpha*derivative it is equivalent to adding a certain number(negative times negative is positive). So that results in the increase of the parameters.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept my answer as correct and upvote it :)